# Can not login to phpmyadmin with root user

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-17.04

I am having trouble to login to with phpmyadmin in Ubuntu system.

Username - root
Password - empty

but still it show me error like below

```
 #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Help me to solve it
Thank you.

Comment: You have to reinstall mysql ,thats the only way i found when I had similar trouble for ubuntu 14.04 and try disallowing remote login this time

Comment: that means the password is not correct. you have to provide the correct password.You can reset the password using command line:-[Resetting forgotten phpmyadmin password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321903/resetting-forgotten-phpmyadmin-password)

Comment: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sloved it with below steps:

1) Open `config.inc.php` file

2) Change file permition to write

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

3) Add below line to the file

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'MY_SQL ROOT_USER_PASSWORD';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

4) Change file parmissions to original again

```
 sudo chmod 755 /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

5) Restart server

```
service mysql start or service mysql start
```

6) open

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
username: root
password: YOUR_MYSQL'S ROOT USER'S PASSWORD
```

- Successfully logged in to phpmyadmin.

Comment: **This is an incredibly insecure solution.** You're setting you phpMyAdmin to be completely open to whoever can connect to it. You probably don't even want to do this on a private network because of possible XSS attacks.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct answer:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`

Comment: I was not trying to use a blank root password as that is completely insecure, but still could not login. The above did not work for me. However this did work (https://manurevah.com/blah/en/p/Re-Allowing-root-access-to-PhpMyAdmin)  
From shell login as root: mysql -u root -p mysql
Remove the plugin value from root: update user set
plugin='' where user='root';
Flush: flush privileges;

To set it back use to disallow root via phpmyadmin: update user set
plugin='unix_socket' where user='root';

Answer (score 1):

in terminal, type

```
sudo gedit '/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php'
```

The user file will get open
 Just check the username like

```
$dbuser='phpmyadmin';
```

And password like

```
$dbpass='1234';
```

Just copy this username and password without quotes in login page.

Comment: How do you login as `root` using the credentials for phpMyAdmin's user?

Comment: This answer is wrong. Those are the credentials created by dbconfig for extra phpMyAdmin features. That will be a limited user that you should not use.