# phpMyAdmin Cannot log in to the MySQL server on Centos 7

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, centos7, mysql-8.0

I installed `mysql-community-server-8.0.13-1.el7.x86_64` on Centos 7 with Nginx, and added the phpMyAdmin to manage the databases but I keep getting error `Cannot log in to the MySQL server` from phpMyAdmin. I've tried the following and have been struggling for a few days now:

- Changed some of the parameters (suggested on stackoverflow) located on `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` like the following but no luck:

  ```
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';          
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
  ```
- I've tried mysql shell, and I'm able to login with `root` and other users. But, I have no idea why it fails on phpMyAdmin. Please help and thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not login to phpmyadmin with root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486683/can-not-login-to-phpmyadmin-with-root-user)

Comment: @Stony thanks for the help but it didn't worked.

Comment: Does /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock exist?

Comment: @Light.G Yes, it's there. I guess my option would be to uninstall and reinstall MySQL

Comment: When you log in from the command line client, please run the `STATUS;` command to see the connection type (whether some host "via TCP/IP" or "Localhost via UNIX socket"). Also note the path to the UNIX socket if it's provided. How have you installed phpMyAdmin - through the package manager or by downloading and uncompressing it yourself?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch This is what it shows: `Connection:Localhost via UNIX socket` and `UNIX socket:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` and I verified all

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I installed it thru package manager. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by doing the following: 
*(I should mention that this solution works for MySQL 8.0.13 and phpMyAdmin 4.8.4 - Both, latest version today)*

1- I edited `config.inc.php` with these server parameters (only):

```
/*** This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in 
cookie. Needs to be 32 chars long. */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'generate_your_blowfish_secret_32_chars'; 

/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

2- On MySQL terminal

```
//Create a new user:
mysql> CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';

//Grant all privileges:
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* To 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

//Flush all privileges:
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

//Change authentication_string with password:
mysql> ALTER USER user IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 
'your_password';

//Login with the new user and password!
```

This should allow you to login into phpMyAdmin. I hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

This work for  me :

```
sudo mysql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'YourNewPassword';
```

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 7, I had to:

1. uncomment the "default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password" line in /etc/my.cnf
   (then systemctl restart mysqld)
2. ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your-password';

A minor tweak on the accepted answer from Jacman above. I had tried everything else, but was missing the 'WITH mysql_native_password' clause