# Can't log in to phpMyAdmin with root, but can access MySQL from command line

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to set up phpMyAdmin on my server. I'm able to access it by going to mydomain.com/phpmyadmin, but when I try to log in, I get the error "Cannot log in to the MySQL server", even though I'm able to log in to MariaDB with the same credentials on the command line.

[image]

My nginx.conf:

```
#startup file.
user nginx nginx;

#usually equal to number of CPUs you have. run command "grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l" to find it
worker_processes  auto;
worker_cpu_affinity auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Keeps the logs free of messages about not being able to bind().
#daemon     off;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
#   rewrite_log on;

    include mime.types;
    default_type       application/octet-stream;
    access_log         /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    sendfile           on;
#   tcp_nopush         on;
    keepalive_timeout  3;
#   tcp_nodelay        on;
#   gzip               on;
        #php max upload limit cannot be larger than this       
    client_max_body_size 13m;
    index              index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for PHP.
    upstream php {
                #this should match value of "listen" directive in php-fpm pool
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    include sites-enabled/*;

    include snippets/phpMyAdmin.conf;

}
```

snippets/phpMyAdmin.conf:

```
server {

server_name mydomain.com;

location /phpmyadmin {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    deny all;
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        root /var/www/html;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root /var/www/html;
    }

}
location /phpMyAdmin {
   rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
}

}
```

config.inc.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * phpMyAdmin configuration file, you can use it as base for the manual
 * configuration. For easier setup you can use "setup/".
 *
 * All directives are explained in Documentation.html and on phpMyAdmin
 * wiki <http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net>.
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/**
 * Server(s) configuration
 */
$i = 0;

// The $cfg['Servers'] array starts with $cfg['Servers'][1].  Do not use
// $cfg['Servers'][0]. You can disable a server config entry by setting host
// to ''. If you want more than one server, just copy following section
// (including $i incrementation) serveral times. There is no need to define
// full server array, just define values you need to change.
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'localhost'; // MySQL hostname or IP address
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';          // MySQL port - leave blank for default port
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';          // Path to the socket - leave blank for default socket
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';       // How to connect to MySQL server ('tcp' or 'socket')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';    // The php MySQL extension to use ('mysql' or 'mysqli')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;       // Use compressed protocol for the MySQL connection
                                                    // (requires PHP >= 4.3.0)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '';          // MySQL control user settings
                                                    // (this user must have read-only
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '';          // access to the "mysql/user"
                                                    // and "mysql/db" tables).
                                                    // The controluser is also
                                                    // used for all relational
                                                    // features (pmadb)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';    // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)?
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = '';          // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '';          // MySQL password (only needed
                                                    // with 'config' auth_type)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db']       = '';          // If set to a db-name, only
                                                    // this db is displayed in left frame
                                                    // It may also be an array of db-names, where sorting order is relevant.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db']       = '';          // Database name to be hidden from listings
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = '';          // Verbose name for this host - leave blank to show the hostname

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']         = '';          // Database used for Relation, Bookmark and PDF Features
                                                    // (see scripts/create_tables.sql)
                                                    //   - leave blank for no support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'phpmyadmin'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = '';          // Bookmark table
                                                    //   - leave blank for no bookmark support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_bookmark'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation']      = '';          // table to describe the relation between links (see doc)
                                                    //   - leave blank for no relation-links support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_relation'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info']    = '';          // table to describe the display fields
                                                    //   - leave blank for no display fields support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_table_info'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords']  = '';          // table to describe the tables position for the PDF schema
                                                    //   - leave blank for no PDF schema support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_table_coords'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages']     = '';          // table to describe pages of relationpdf
                                                    //   - leave blank if you don't want to use this
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_pdf_pages'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info']   = '';          // table to store column information
                                                    //   - leave blank for no column comments/mime types
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_column_info'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history']       = '';          // table to store SQL history
                                                    //   - leave blank for no SQL query history
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_history'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose_check'] = TRUE;        // set to FALSE if you know that your pma_* tables
                                                    // are up to date. This prevents compatibility
                                                    // checks and thereby increases performance.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot']     = TRUE;        // whether to allow root login
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order']           // Host authentication order, leave blank to not use
                                     = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules']           // Host authentication rules, leave blank for defaults
                                     = array();
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']              // Allow logins without a password. Do not change the FALSE
                                     = FALSE;       // default unless you're running a passwordless MySQL server
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords']              // Leave blank (default) for no Designer support, otherwise
                                     = '';          // set to suggested 'pma_designer_coords' if really needed
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold']         // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = 50;          //   DEFAULT: '50'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold']      // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = '32M';       //   DEFAULT: '32M'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout']         // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = 600;         //   DEFAULT: '600'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold']        // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = '32M';       //   DEFAULT: '32M'
/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/upload';
$cfg['SaveDir']   = '/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/save';

/*
 * Disable the default warning that is displayed on the DB Details Structure
 * page if any of the required Tables for the relation features is not found
 */
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = TRUE;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin 4.4.x is no longer maintained by upstream, but security fixes
 * are still backported by downstream.
 */
$cfg['VersionCheck'] = FALSE;
?>
```

Comment: this answer your question ? [https://askubuntu.com/a/175205](https://askubuntu.com/a/175205)

Comment: see this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50487425/12740160](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50487425/12740160)

Comment: I'm on CentOS, so I can't use dpkg-reconfigure

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, hoping this helps someone. Turns out MariaDB was not running. I had run `systemctl list-unit-files` which showed mariadb.service as "enabled", and I thought this meant the same thing as active.

However, running `systemctl mariadb status` showed the following:

```
mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mariadb.service entered failed state.
mariadb.service failed.
```

I ran `pkill mysqld`, `pkill mysqld_ssafe`, and `systemctl mariadb restart`, and voila, was able to log in to phpMyAdmin

Comment: This actually doesn't make sense unless you have two database servers running on your system; you wouldn't have been able to log in from the command line client if the service wasn't running. Perhaps the problem that caused MariaDB to exit occurred after you connected from the CLI and before trying to connect to phpMyAdmin? The log file might have some hint about why it failed. Regardless, it's quite strange to be able to connect to a process that isn't running, so I would suggest that you keep investigating the root cause.